# Generate random using button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, button

How can I get a button to generate a random emoji (from a list of emojis) every time it is clicked using JavaScript.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: please show what have you tried so far

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to store your emojis as their hex values, not as their HTML entity encoded form. Also, it seems the Unicode values you picked map to Japanese characters, not emojis. Here's a working (except for actually using Japanese characters) script that I cleaned up a bit:

```js
var emojis = [0x128512, 0x128516, 0x128513, 0x128514];
var display = document.getElementById('emojiDisplay');

function displayEmoji(){
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * emojis.length);
  var emoji = emojis[random];         
  display.innerHTML=`<h2>${String.fromCharCode(emoji)}</h2>`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the emoji list in the funcition

```js
var emojiList = ['&#128512', '&#128516', '&#128513', '&#128514'];
var display = document.getElementById('emojiDisplay');

function displayEmoji() {

 
  let randomEmojiIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * emojiList.length);
  emoji = emojiList[randomEmojiIndex];
  
  display.innerHTML = `<h2>${emoji}</h2>`;

}
```